# GenericDataRepository with Compiled Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, compiled-query

I have a MVC project with many layers(View,Model,DataAccess,Business) and I am using GenericDataRepository in my DataAccessLayer. I would like to enhance the GenericDataRepository's performance with CompiledQueries.

here is my GenericDataRepository with only one function to keep it simple...

```
public class GenericDataRepository<T> : IGenericDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = null;
        using (var context = new ZenHaberDBEntities())
        {
            query = context.Set<T>();

            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
                query = query.Include(include);

            if (filter != null)
                query = query.Where(filter);

            if (orderBy != null)
                query = orderBy(query);

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

and this is the code in BusinessLayer that uses GenericDataRepository to pull data from DB.

```
public IList<Article> GetAllArticles()
{
    return _articleRepository.Get();
}
```

Can I add GetAllArticles() function to CompiledQueries? Does anyone have any experience on this?

here is my context

```
public partial class ZenHaberDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public ZenHaberDBEntities()
        : base("name=ZenHaberDBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Article> Article { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ArticleMedia> ArticleMedia { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ArticleTagRelation> ArticleTagRelation { get; set;       }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Weather> Weather { get; set; }
}


public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static ObjectContext ToObjectContext(this DbContext dbContext)
    {
        return (dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your `context` class also ?

Comment: @Sampath, I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompiledQueries` are only compatible with ObjectContext-derived models, and it is not compatible with DbContext-derived models.Hence you have derived it using `DbContext` where you cannot use `CompiledQueries`.

But you have so many other options to improve the performance of your Linq quires.Below article shows lot of details about it.

[**Performance Considerations for EF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

**Note :** If you need to see about the `CompiledQuery` section, please see it under this title on the above link : **3.3 Using CompiledQuery to improve performance with LINQ queries**

Comment: Can I convert DbContect to ObjectContext easily? I have to read abou it. some info would be great :)

Comment: please see the **Note** section.